# What does ObjectReference.VariableName mean?

Tags: java

### I didn't understand this part:

Instance variables can be accessed directly by calling the variable name inside the class. However, within static methods (when instance variables are given accessibility), they should be called using the fully qualified name. ObjectReference.VariableName.

Can you give an example please ?

Comment: "Can you give an example please " Probably every Java code ever written.

Comment: what part of that don't you understand?

Comment: You really need to clear your **basic fundamentals of programming**

Comment: Actually, @OHGODSPIDERS, that's a reference to a static variable, not to an instance variable from within a static method.

Answer (score 1):

Static methods are methods that are called without a reference to an instance of that object. So instance variables cannot be called statically, as each instance will have its own values. So in a static method, you need a specific instance of an object in order to know which value of the instance variable you are trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is how you access these variables:

```
class myClass {
public static int staticVar;
public int nonStaticVar;
//Constructor initialises both
}
```

Static approach:

```
int otherVariable = MyClass.staticVar;
```

As you can see, for the static variable you do not need to make an object to access it. Note that you can imagine a static variable to have the trait "once per class", which means, that you can not have 2 versions of staticVar.

Non Static (instance variable):

```
MyClass instanceOfMyClass = new myClass();
int otherVariable2 = instanceOfMyClass.nonStaticVar;
```

To have 2 versions of nonStaticVar you can simply make 2 objects and give this variable different values in the 2 objects. Note that in this case you have to make an object.